# How would someone add a simple On/Off switch for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

First time poster here and I've got a fairly novice question for you.  I'd like to write a simple module that lets an administrator in Wordpress turn an HTML snippet on and off with a simple check box.  The idea is fairly straight forward.  Depending on the weather, his business will either be "In Service" or "Out of Service".

I know this is probably a bit simple for most, but I'm just not stepping into Wordpress and wasnt sure where to begin with something like this.  Any direction would be fantastic.  Thanks!

Comment: Learn Wordpress and PHP. Sorry to sound harsh, but this really is the only direction at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use a Wordpress Widget.  A text display widget ships with Wordpress out of the box.

Here is the WP Codex link explaining Widgets.
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to just wrap the html snippet in javascript. I'm not sure the best way to make it "toggleable" though - you might need to code it as an actual plugin and add a page to the control panel with a custom widget.

The good news is that such a plugin should be **very** easy, even with only basic skills.